# Wordpress Photo Gallery with Page Number

Tags: wordpress

How can i create photo gallery with page number like this link? Which plugin is this?

http://senoecoseno.it/looney-tunes-e-dc-insieme-mashup-epico-25-foto/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

[prettyphoto-plugin](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)

Comment: This is not what i want. This is “lightbox” plugin. I need plugin which i create a gallery and show the gallerie's photos with page number. ( a photo on each page)